# Can independent plug-ins add views to a RCP perspective?

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, perspective

can different independent plug-ins add views to a RCP perspective?

Answer (score 4):

yes, you have to declare perspectiveExtensions in your own perspective and then make the plugins register the views with that perspectiveExtension.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#viewtutorial_perspective